# Show that (12345) and (12) create $S_5$

Tags: symmetric-groups

Can someone tell me how I can show the following:

> Consider the symmetric group $S_5$ and show that $(12345)$ and $(12)$ generate the group.

Comment: What does "creates" mean here? If it means that those two elements together form a group, then it is false. If it means "generates" then this is trivial by the definition of the word.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think the only interesting variation on this is "show that the two elements generate all of $S_5$". So a mix-up between "a group" and "the group".

Comment: @Arthur Ahh, of course, that makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sorry @all, I meant "the" group, not a group.

Answer (score 1):

So, thats everything I have to show? Or is there something more to do?

Let $c = (1, 2, \dotsc, 5)$.  We see that
\begin{align*}
c (1, 2) c^{-1} &= (2, 3) \\
c (2, 3) c^{-1} &= (3, 4) \\
&\vdots \\
c (5-2, 5-1) c^{-1} &= (5-1, 5),
\end{align*}
so that $(i, i+1) \in \langle (1, 2), c \rangle$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 5-1$.  Next, we have
\begin{align*}
(2, 3) (1, 2) (2, 3)^{-1} &= (1, 3) \\
(3, 4) (1, 3) (3, 4)^{-1} &= (1, 4) \\
&\vdots \\
(5-1, 5) (1, 5-1) (5-1, 5)^{-1} &= (1, 5),
\end{align*}
so that $(1, i) \in \langle (1, 2), c \rangle$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 5$.  Choose any $1 \leq i < j \leq 5$, then
$$ (i, j) = (1, i) (1, j) (1, i)^{-1} \in \langle (1, 2), c \rangle. $$
Therefore, $\langle (1, 2), c \rangle$ contains all transpositions.  Hence, $\langle (1, 2), c \rangle = S_5$.

Comment: This is a funny (in a good way) use of $\vdots$ :-)